# I am facing below error while running the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing below error while running the query

```sql
SELECT (0.01 * CAST(instruct_to_bal_avl_aft AS INT) )
FROM [FullYear].[dbo].[aa_momo_log]
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3.0' to data type int.

Comment: Well...that is because you have a varchar value of 3.0 which can't be converted to an int. Try it yourself and you will see.  select cast('3.0' as int)

Comment: To solve this you probably will need to first convert your string to a decimal. Then convert the decimal to int. Then ask yourself why you are storing integers as string representations of decimals. select convert(int, convert(decimal(7,2), '3.0'))

Comment: rule of thumb, if you're going to do math on a column you don't want it stored as a string.

Comment: Oracle, DB2 and others return 3 when doing cast('3.0' as int).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are multiplying by a float value you can cast as DECIMAL instead of INT:

```
SELECT (0.01 * CAST(instruct_to_bal_avl_aft AS DECIMAL) )
FROM [FullYear].[dbo].[aa_momo_log]
```